# debuild fails on library requiring Python2.6

Tags: python, debian, deb, dpkg

I am trying to debianize a python package that requires Python 2.6 using stdeb. The build fails because it forces setup.py to be run with python2.5, which can't parse the python 2.6 "except Exception as e" syntax which leads to a final:

```
dpkg-buildpackage: error: fakeroot debian/rules clean gave error exit status 2
```

I am running this on Debian Squeeze using python-stdeb 0.6.0-1, debhelper 8.0.0, dpkg 1.15.8.13, and devscripts 2.10.69+squeeze4.

So, is there a way to tell debuild "please use python 2.6, pretty please"?

Comment: seems like someone had a similar problem and solved it :  http://jira.freeswitch.org/browse/FS-2797?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:changehistory-tabpanel

Comment: It's related, but not exactly the same. I haven't been able to find the place that has embedded python2.5.

Comment: there's always the brute force method: rename the python2.5 executable and create a symlink for python2.5 -> python2.6